# rcpp assign value to dataframe

Tags: arrays, dataframe, rcpp

I'm trying to learn Rcpp so I can process data more efficiently in R.

The goal is to input a dataframe, run some calculations and update those fields. The first challenge I have is updating a cell in a dataframe. The code doesn't actually update the outputting data and I'm not sure why. any insight is appreciated.

```
    library(Rcpp)
a <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:10,5,rep=TRUE)))

cppFunction('Rcpp::DataFrame why(DataFrame a){

//breakout dataframe into arrays 
Rcpp::NumericVector test0 = a[0];
Rcpp::NumericVector test1 = a[1];
Rcpp::NumericVector test2 = a[2];
Rcpp::NumericVector test3 = a[3];
Rcpp::NumericVector test4 = a[4];
Rcpp::NumericVector test5 = a[5];
Rcpp::NumericVector test6 = a[6];
Rcpp::NumericVector test7 = a[7];
Rcpp::NumericVector test8 = a[8];
Rcpp::NumericVector test9 = a[9];

// create varialbe "g" to store a value
  int g = (test0[0]*3) ; 
// replace the current value stored in test0[0] with the value stored in "g"     
  test0[0] = g;

  Rcpp::DataFrame oput = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b0") = test[0],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b1") = test[1],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b2") = test[2],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b3") = test[3],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b4") = test[4],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b5") = test[5],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b6") = test[6],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b7") = test[7],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b8") = test[8],
                                                  Rcpp::Named("b9") = test[9]
  );
  //output disappointing results that make me question learning R in the first place
         return oput;
            
 }'     )  
 
 check <- why(a) 
 View(check)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow and Rcpp.  You may find the data.frame example in the [RcppExamples](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples) package (also on CRAN [here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples)) useful as a first start.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.